# How to add HTML to page following user/register to track Google AdWords conversions?

Tags: 7, hooks, advertising

I want to track conversions for Google AdWords. Basically I want to track when people sign up via the user register page (i.e. when they click join).

Google provides code (which is basically a little image) which it says I have to add to the page I want to track. I figure I need to add this to the page which comes after the visitor clicks the join button at the bottom of the `user/register` page.

(1) Is there a module to do this (Drupal 7)? OR
(2) How can I add HTML to the page following the `user/register` page (perhaps using `hook_page_alter`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of GA or some of the social plugins, you can just add the code in a custom block with FULL HTML format, so you can try creating custom block (maybe in footer) with your code and set the pages where it will appear to `user/register`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want it to occur in the `user/register` page, I want it to appear in the page that comes after the user actually says yes to registering. What page is that?

Comment: You can make a custom page for this purposes (i.e. with path `user/welcome`) and place the code on it. There is a module LoginToboggan it can set the redirection path after new registrations, or create redirect rule in Rules.